# Test email rendering - HTML raw source or HTML pre send?

Tags: email, html-email

I am testing some HTML email layout, I am not sure to understand which is the HTML I should consider:

- use the HTML as it is sent from my server to mailgun (an email service provider)?
- use the HTML as I receive it in raw format in the email I receive?

The difference is that in the raw source I receive there are =3D and =20 characters because of the quoted printable format. I'm using testi@ but I suppose any rendering software will do, just it's not clear which version of the HTML should be used (needless to say I see =20 everywhere if it's raw, whereas it's perfect if I use the "pure" HTML)

Comment: You should use the HTML as it is before being sent. I'm unsure of how testi@ works but with other services such as Litmus & Email on Acid you can send a test to them directly from your ESP and they will process that for the previews.

Comment: Thanks, I've found the same functionality and sent the email, if you like you can reply and say to look for the send function so that the rendering software can simulate properly

Comment: @Gwesolo add your comment as an answer to close the question. It´s a good one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the HTML as it is before being sent. I'm unsure of how testi@ works but with other services such as Litmus & Email on Acid you can send a test to them directly from your ESP and they will process that for the previews.

[Added from comment on question to allow close]